# Write your own Death Note

Tags: code-golf

#### Kira needs your help!

---

### Input format:

```
Date [and/or Time]
Name
Gender
Reason
```

### Output format:

```
<Last Name, First Name> <will die/died> on the <DD><st/nd/rd/th> of <MMM, YYYY> [at <hh:mm:ss TT>].
<He/She> <will die/died> of <Reason>.
```

---

---

## Details, Details:

---

Your program should account for at least the following date input formats:

```
9 November 2003
9/11/2003
November 9, 2003
```

---

Time formats:

```
hh tt
hh TT
hh:mm tt
hh:mm TT
hh:mm:ss tt
hh:mm:ss TT
HH
HH:mm
HH:mm:ss
```

---

The following name input formats:

```
first        // Stephen
last         // Harper
first last   // Stephen Harper
last, first  // Harper, Stephen
```

---

---

## Test cases:

---

### Input:

```
2 September 1973
J.R.R. Tolkien
Male
pneumonia
```

### Output:

> Tolkien, J.R.R. died on the 2nd of
>   September, 1973.
>
> He died of pneumonia.

---

**DISCLAIMER:** If he actually dies on this date, it's *Kira's* fault, not mine.

**UPDATE:** Stephen Harper did not die on the listed date

### Input:

```
21/12/12 23:59:59             // DD/MM/YY HH:mm:ss
Harper, Stephen               // Last, First
Unknown                       // Gender
a heart attack for no reason  // Reason
```

### Output:

> Harper, Stephen will die on the 21st
>   of December, 2012 at 11:59:59 PM.
>
> Harper, Stephen will die of a heart
>   attack for no reason.

---

---

### Bonus:

```
July 21, 1969 02:56:15 GMT
Armstrong, Neil
Male
poisoned moon cheese

--

January 19, 2038 03:14:08 GMT
Everyone
Unknown
Y2K38
```

Add `<st/nd/rd/th>` at the end of `DD` for input.

Comment: Ahaha I just finished reading this series :D Shouldn't it be "heart attack" for "no reason" then?

Comment: Um, September 2nd is 2/9/11, not 2/7/11 ;)

Comment: Does the gender not have any effect on the output?

Comment: Also, do we have to accept dates before 1970?

Comment: Gender does have an effect on the output, look at test case #1.

Comment: @minitech Don't spoil anything! I'm only about one-thirds done. :)

Comment: @Peter Dates before 1970 are Bonus.

Comment: Did you get this idea from Osama's death?

Comment: @SHiNKiROU Nope. :) BTW, who's "Osama"?

Comment: Could we get a clear specification on which date and name formats are required?

Comment: Your input format labeled with `hh:mm:ss` is actually `HH:mm:ss`, while the output format is ... weird (and actually hh:mm:ss tt).

Comment: @Joey If you could fix up any of my mistakes/logical errors, or improve it (change level of difficulty) in any way, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: How do we disambiguate between input with DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: @Peter <s>Sorry, that's why I said to fix it if you see any errors. In this case, it would've been difficult to decide on your part, so I'll tell you I take ISO's side: `DD/MM/YYYY`.</s> If you look closely, you'll see there is no `MM/DD/YYYY`. But again, fix it if you think it'll make it clearer.

Comment: Your output format implies that the day has two digits, whereas it only has one in the sample output.

Comment: And I think with that exhaustive list of date formats you killed it. The only reasonable approach left by now is probably to embed all formats.

Comment: @muntoo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Osama_bin_Laden

Comment: @Chris lol*, I was joking. :) *Resists urge to capitalize "lol".

Comment: Wait, now we have to accept simply first/last names too? 1. That doesn't work in the DN and 2. That makes things so much more difficult to golf :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Javascript (561)

This can probably be reduced significantly, but here goes:

```
i=i.split("\n");d=new Date(i[0]);t=d.getDate();z=t%10;t+=z==1?"st":z==2?"nd":z==3?"rd":"th";m=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'][d.getMonth()];y=d.getFullYear();a=d.getHours();b=d.getMinutes();c=d.getSeconds();l=a&&b&&c?" at "+a+":"+b+":"+c:"";g=d>new Date()?"will die":"died";n=i[1].split(" ");n[1]?n[0][n[0].length-1]==","?n=i[1]:n=n[1]+", "+n[0]:n[0];s=i[2]=="Male"?"He":i[2]=="Female"?"She":n;document.write(n+" "+g+" on the "+t+" of "+m+", "+y+l+".<br>"+s+" "+g+" of "+i[3]+".");
```

Sample I/O:

```
2 September 1973
J.R.R. Tolkien
Male
pneumonia
```

> Tolkien, J.R.R. died on the 2nd of September, 1973.
>   He died of pneumonia.

```
January 19, 2038 03:14:08 GMT
Everyone
Unknown
Y2K38
```

> Everyone will die on the 18th of January, 2038 at 21:14:8.
>   Everyone will die of Y2K38.

Try it out on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28fCg/4/).

Comment: Just want to point out that `i="9 November 2003 03:14:08 GMT\nDouglas Adams\nMale\nI forgot";` gives me the `8th of November`.

Comment: @muntoo That's because it adjusts to your timezone. If you live in the GMT timezone, it should give you 9th.

Comment: I'm going to blame **you** if I die on my birthday. :P

Answer (score 5):

### VB.NET, <s>727</s> 695

Okay, golfed a bit. Requires `Option Strict Off`.

```
Module M
Sub Main
Dim d=Date.Parse(Console.ReadLine),n=Console.ReadLine,o=Date.Now,g=Console.ReadLine,r=Console.ReadLine,i=n.IndexOf(" "),f=d.Day Mod 10+(d.Day\10=1)*5,a=Array.IndexOf("male|female|he|she|him|her|guy|girl|boy|lady|man|woman".Split("|"), g.ToLower),b="|st|nd|rd".Split("|"),m="|January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December".Split("|")
If n.IndexOf(",")<0 Then n=n.Substring(i+1)&", "&n.Substring(0,i)
g=If(a<0,n,If(a Mod 2,"She","He"))
Console.Write("{0} {11} on the {1}{2} of {3}, {4} at {5}:{6:00}:{7:00}.{8}{9} {11} of {10}.",n,d.Day,If(f<4,b(f),"th"),m(d.Month),d.Year,d.Hour,d.Minute,d.Second,vbCrLf,g,r,If(o<d,"will die","died"))
End Sub
End Module
```

It accepts the dates in all the test cases, and many other formats thanks to `Date.Parse`. It accepts *many* genders (as you can see) as well. If Kira decides to put only the person's first or last name, the program will crash.

Comment: looks like you may be able to drop quite a few bytes by replacing your split argument with a `MonthName(d.Month)` call

Answer (score 2):

#### CSharp - 463 chars

```
void Main(){Func<String>c=()=>Console.ReadLine();var d=DateTime.Parse(c());var n=c();if(!n.Contains(",")&&n.Contains(" "))n=n.Split(' ')[1]+", "+n.Split(' ')[0];n+=" ";var g=c().ToLower();g=g.Contains("male")?g.Replace("female","She").Replace("male","He"):"They";var r=c();var f=(DateTime.Now<d);Console.Write(String.Format(n+"{0} on the {1} {2}\n{3} {0} of {4}",(f?"will die":"died"),d.ToString("dddd 'of' MMMM, yyyy"),d.Date==d?"":d.ToString("hh:mm:ss"),g,r));}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <strike>509</strike> <strike>474</strike> <strike>462</strike> 461 characters

```
<?for($l=0;$l<4;)$i[$l++]=chop(fgets(STDIN));
putenv('TZ=GMT');
$t=strtotime(preg_match("/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)(.*)/",$i[0],$q)?"$q[1]-$q[2]-".($q[3]<100?19+1*($q[3]<70):"").$q[3].$q[4]:$i[0]);
$z=$t<time()?" died":" will die";
$f="jS \of F, Y".($t%86400?" \a\\t g:i:s A":"");
$n=strpos($i[1],',')?$i[1]:explode(" ",$i[1]);
if(is_array($n))$n=$n[1]!=""?$n[1].", ".$n[0]:$n[0];?>
<?=$n."$z on the ".date($f,$t)."\n\n".($i[2][0]==M?He:($i[2][0]==F?She:$n))."$z of ".$i[3];
```

I've added newlines after each `;` but not counted them as they don't need to be there.
Whether the code handles dates beyond January 19, 2038 03:14:07, depends on whether it's run on a 64bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, <sub><s>384</s></sub> 366 Bytes

#### Golfed

Full `sub`routine that takes input of expected type `Variant\String` and outputs the associated deathnote message to the VBE immediates window

*Note: VBA is incapable of handling Timezones without declaring Windows API functions, so as these are not necessary for the question, they have been excluded*

```vb
Sub x(d,n,g,r)
e=CDate(d)
f=Day(e) Mod 10
w=IIf(e>Now," will die"," died")
i=InStr(1,n," ")
n=IIf(InStr(1,n,","),n,Mid(n,i+1)&", "&Mid(n,1,i-1))
g=LCase(g)
Debug.?n;w" on the "Day(e)Split("th|st|nd|rd","|")(IIf(f>3,0,f))" of "MonthName(Month(e))", "Year(e)IIf(InStr(1,d,":")," at "&TimeValue(d),"")"."vbCr;IIf(g="male","He",IIf(g="female","She",n))w" of "r".
End Sub
```

#### Bonus Verison, <sub><s>394</s></sub> 376 Bytes

Slightly modified version of the above that handles all of the bonus cases with the exception of timezones (Correction for handling mononyms)

```vb
Sub x(d,n,g,r)
e=CDate(d)
f=Day(e) Mod 10
i=InStr(1,n," ")
w=Space(0 ^i)&IIf(e>Now,"will die","died")
n=IIf(InStr(1,n,",")^i,n,Mid(n,i+1)&", "&Mid(n,1,i))
g=LCase(g)
Debug.?n;w" on the "Day(e)Split("th|st|nd|rd","|")(IIf(f>3,0,f))" of "MonthName(Month(e))", "Year(e)IIf(InStr(1,d,":")," at "&TimeValue(d),"")"."vbCr;IIf(g="male","He",IIf(g="female","She",n))w" of "r".
End Sub
```

#### Usage

input and output sequence of the example problems as seen from the VBE immediate window

```
?Now
01-Jun-17 1:59:35 PM

x "2 September 1973", "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Male", "pneumonia"
Tolkien, J.R.R. died on the 2nd of September, 1973.
He died of pneumonia.

x "21/12/12 23:59:59", "Harper, Stephen", "Unknown", "a heart attack for no reason"
Harper, Stephen died on the 21st of December, 2012 at 11:59:59 PM.
Harper, Stephen died of a heart attack for no reason.

x "July 21, 1969 02:56:15", "Armstrong, Neil", "Male", "poisoned moon cheese"
Armstrong, Neil died on the 21st of July, 1969 at 2:56:15 AM.
He died of poisoned moon cheese.

## Using Bonus Version

x "January 19, 2038 03:14:08","Everyone","Unknown","Y2K38"
Everyone will die on the 19th of January, 2038 at 3:14:08 AM.
Everyone will die of Y2K38.
```